# Want “tree” output utf8

Tags: unicode, ascii

```
▶ tree 下载 -L 1
\344\270\213\350\275\275
├── BT
├── ISO
├── Let\ s\ Play\ -\ Sniper\ Elite\ v2\ Nazi\ Zombie\ Army.flv
├── sniper\ elite\ v2\ 02.flv
└── \350\275\257\344\273\266\345\214\205
```

those 7-bit ASCII output is non identifiable to human. Normally I use `ascii2uni -a K` to convert into UTF8. but in Fedora 25, the `uni2ascii` is not in repo. So any other way to make it output UTF8?

Answer (score 7):

I found [another answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37236526/prevent-unix-tree-from-displaying-back-slash-before-spaces). Making changes to my locale settings didn't help at all, but using the `-N` option with tree did.

```
# tree -if ./my-path/
./my-path/Olaf\ Hund\ Vs\ Ursari\ De\ Clejani\ _\ Taraf\ De\ Hai\210douks\ _\ Koçani\ Orkestar\ -\ electric\ gypsyl.mp3


# tree -ifN  ./my-path/
./my-path/Olaf Hund Vs Ursari De Clejani _ Taraf De Haïdouks _ Koçani Orkestar - electric gypsyl.mp3
```

Note that this also un-escapes spaces.

Comment: It's 2 years post, fc31 is OK now. No need -N or any other command switch.

Comment: What is fc31? Another command line tool?

Comment: -N fix Chinese issue.

Answer (score 1):

Set the encoding to `UTF-8` (and choose an appropriate locale that has support for Unicode) e.g.:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 tree -L 1 下载
```

Presumably you are using a locale that can not interpret those characters (`C` maybe?).

**Example:**

```
% LC_ALL=C tree 下载 
\344\270\213\350\275\275
`-- foo

% LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 tree 下载 
下载
└── foo
```

Comment: LC_ALL not work at all. all LC_* except LC_ALL is "zh_CN.UTF-8" in `locale`. https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/zRVhleLJRQgN~AkwC28q8F5M1UNdIGYhyRLivL9gydE=